# Create new table using better-sqlite3

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, express, better-sqlite3

I am trying to create a new table using **node.js** and **better-sqlite3**. When I execute the file, it returns the following error:

```
ReferenceError: createtable is not defined at Object.<anonymous> (...my file's path...)
```

How can I solve it?
Here's my code:

```
const express = require('express');
var createError = require('http-errors');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const sqlitedb = require('better-sqlite3');

const createTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users('name' varchar, 'surname' varchar, 'date_of_birth' DATE DEFAULT, 'email' varchar, 'username' varchar PRIMARY KEY, 'password' varchar );"

const dbusers = './databaseUsers.sqlite3';
let db = new sqlitedb(dbusers , sqlitedb.OPEN_READWRITE, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }
    verbose: console.log}
);

db.exec(createtable);
```

Thank you in advance ;)

Comment: Typo in `verbose: console.log}`

Comment: Thanks @RokoC.Buljan, I upvoted your comment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a typo in the variable declaration. The variable you declared is **createTable** instead of **createtable** (note the capitalized T). So it should be:

```
db.exec(createTable);
```

Comment: Whoops. Thank you very much! Do you also have any advice about how to continue from that point on?